# How do I remove a value from the list(s) containing that value?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of lists in a code that contains UserIDs and what are they doing with program.

for example:

```cs
List<string> WaitingForActivation = new List<string>();
List<string> DoingFirstThing = new List<string>();
List<string> DoingSecondThing = new List<string>();
List<string> DoingThirdThing = new List<string>();
...
```

and if one user is waiting for activation, user's ID will be added to `WaitingForActivation`.

Whenever user clicks a button, the program checks the lists and do something depending on which list contains the userID.

Sometimes, an error occurs in program and the job won't finish. I have a `try/catch` in which these errors are managed. I want to remove the userID from the list(s) that contains it but I don't know which list contains it.

I can handle it with this code:

```cs
if(WaitingForActivation.Contains(value)) WaitingForActivation.Remove(value);
if(DoingFirstThing.Contains(value)) DoingFirstThing.Remove(value);
if(DoingSecondThing.Contains(value)) DoingSecondThing.Remove(value);
if(DoingThirdThing.Contains(value)) DoingThirdThing.Remove(value);
...
```

but I'm looking for a simpler way because the lists are too many.

Is it possible to somehow remove this value from list(s) which contains it?

Comment: What about using a dictionary to keep / track in which list the userid residents?

Comment: _"Is it possible to somehow remove this value from list(s) which contains it?"_ -- of course it's possible. You've already demonstrated one approach. However, there is no "magic" in C# that would remove the item from all automatically. It's up to you to track the lists, and remove the item. A couple notes: 1) there's no need to call `Contains()`...`Remove()` will ignore values that are not in the list, and 2) one obvious way to keep track of your lists is to put them into a list of lists, e.g. `List<List<string>>`, and then just `foreach` that list, removing the value from each list.

Comment: please use reflection